# How to use IFS_READ & IFS_WRITE services?

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol, db2-400

I've recently heard about the "new" IFS_READ and IFS_WRITE services for IBM i (formerly known as AS/400 or iSeries). I couldn't find documentation for them, and most of what I did find talked about them in general terms. The few sources that went into more detail were focused entirely on RPG, but I would like to use them in ILE COBOL.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: According to this [IBM document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=is-ifs-read-ifs-read-binary-ifs-read-utf8-table-functions), IFS_READ is a part of SQL.  Here's IBM [Embedded SQL statements in COBOL applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=language-embedded-sql-statements-in-cobol-applications) document.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I don't think asking for an example of how to use an API is off topic here. It's not like he is asking for any 3rd party resources, just a simple example.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy You're correct - the question and title may need an edit but its main point does match. I'm voting to reopen and leave a better comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly suggest to have a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which will help you to refine the question (edit) to better match in this site.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418292)

Answer (score 5):

The `IFS_READ` and `IFS_WRITE` API's are sometimes difficult to find, and how to use them would be in an entirely different manual, so let me take a crack at pulling it all together for you.

Both of these API's are DB2 for i services. The documentation for these are not in the Database reference topic, but in the Database performance and query optimization topic found here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=is-ifs-read-ifs-read-binary-ifs-read-utf8-table-functions

You will notice that the `IFS_READ` service is a table function, and the `IFS_WRITE` service is a stored procedure, so to read from the IFS, you can use a select, but to write to the IFS, you will need to use a call. Incidentally, since you would have to use a call, you could almost as easily simply use the stream file functions from C which are `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, and `fclose`. You just need to create COBOL LINKAGE TYPE definitions for them. I will leave that to you since it is not the topic of this question.

So the next question is how do we embed SQL into COBOL. That is described in a different manual: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=programming-coding-sql-statements-in-cobol-applications

In a nutshell you will surround your sql with `EXEC-SQL` and `END-SQL`. But wait there's more. Since the table function can return multiple rows, you can't just use a `SELECT INTO`, you need to open a cursor, fetch from the cursor, then close the cursor.

Something like this:

```
EXEC-SQL
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
  SELECT LINE FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(PATH_NAME => '/usr/file1',
                               END_OF_LINE => 'CRLF')) A
END-SQL.

EXEC-SQL
  OPEN C1
END-SQL.

// in a loop
EXEC-SQL
  FETCH C1 INTO :Host_Variable
END-SQL.

// then once the loop has completed
EXEC-SQL
  CLOSE C1
END-SQL.
```

The syntax for SQL statements can be found in the SQL Reference: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=reference-statements

`IFS_WRITE` is somewhat similar, but you will need to put your SQL call in a loop.

```
// loop for each line you want to write then inside the loop
EXEC-SQL
  CALL QSYS2.IFS_WRITE(PATH_NAME => '/tmp/library_names', 
                     LINE => :host_variable)
END-SQL.
```

Now you might notice that there is no error handling here. SQL will ignore most errors unless you trap them, I will leave that to you.