# DB2 - Is this possible with XMLAGG or LISTAGG?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm new to this sort of thing but here goes.

So I have a problem wherein I collect all the necessary data into a single value column (ONLY 1 COLUMN AND ROW) and output it as a txt file.

My sample code here start with:

```
WITH TEMP AS (
   SELECT COL1 || '|' || COL2 || '|' || 'TEST' || '|' || TRIM(COL3) as concatenated_value from TABLE
)
```

I was able to use LISTAGG using the following code below and got the expected result I need after I converted it into .txt format seen below.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(concatenated_value, x'0d25') as single_field from TEMP
INTO :clob_variable
WHERE COL2 = '0'
GROUP BY COL1;
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMApU.png)

However, I wasn't able to use LISTAGG again when I changed the WHERE clause since apparently the data I was getting was over 4000, so I read some articles that XMLAGG can be used as a replacement. So I've tried it with the following code: (Note that I used the same WHERE CONDITION from above example to shorten the results)

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(
   XMLAGG(
      XMLCONCAT(
         XMLTEXT(concatenated_value),
         XMLTEXT(x'0d25')  
      )
   ) as varchar(32704) into :clob_variable
) FROM TEMP
WHERE COL2 = 0
GROUP BY COL1;
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhWR.png)

Any idea how to replicate the Expected result using XMLAGG? or is there any other way possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  There are better ways to generate a `|` separated text file.  For Db2 for IBM i, consider the `CPYTOIMPF` command.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using DB2 for IBM i as well and i'm using the QSYS2.IFS_WRITE command to output in my IFS directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use IFS\_READ & IFS\_WRITE services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286051/how-to-use-ifs-read-ifs-write-services)

Comment: You're doing it wrong, IFS_WRITE is designed to write one line at a time.  You'll want to call it in a loop.

Comment: I don't think it does since I am already able to write my expected result in my IFS directory if using LISTAGG and less than 4000 characters. I just want to figure out how I can achieve writing the same expected result using XMLAGG or any other method if it can bypass the 4000 character limit. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can extend the limit by casting source like `listagg(cast(concatenated_value as clob(10M)), x'0d25')`

Comment: I'll try this later today. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

See [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-listagg)

> The result data type can exceed VARCHAR(4000), VARBINARY(4000), or
> VARGRAPHIC(2000) if a derived size is used to determine the size of
> the result. The maximum possible value is the maximum for the result
> data type. The following example yields a return data type of
> VARCHAR(10000):

```
LISTAGG(CAST(NAME AS VARCHAR(10000)), ',')
```

*Table 1. Determining the result data type and length* (excerpt)

| Data type of string-expression | Result data type and length |
| --- | --- |
| CHAR(n) or VARCHAR(n) | VARCHAR(MAX(4000, n)) |
| CLOB(n) | CLOB(1M) |

Comment: I don't know if this is correct but I tried using cast but it seems it is still too small. I've declared it as follows:

SELECT LISTAGG(cast(concatenated_value as clob(2G)), x'0d25') AS single_field INTO
:clob_variable  FROM TEMP;

maybe it has something to do with my clob_variable?

I declared it is 
dcl-s clob_variable   sqltype(clob:16773100);